# Sonar complaining logging or rethrowing the exception

Tags: spring-boot, maven, sonarqube

I have the following below piece of code when I am running SonarQube for code quality check on it after integrating it with Maven.

However, Sonar is complaining that I should Either log or rethrow this exception.

What am I missing here? Can some one help me please.

### Code

```
public ShippingResponse processShipping(ShippingRequest request) {
        log.debug("Processing Reservation Request ....");
        try{
            return helper.processShippingMethod(request);
        } catch (ServiceException serviceException) {
            log.error(RESERVATION_EXCE, ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(serviceException));
            throw serviceException;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException(ErrorMessages.EPO_SM_ERR_03, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sonar complaining about logging and rethrowing the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122271/sonar-complaining-about-logging-and-rethrowing-the-exception)

Comment: No my catch block diff compare to above solution

Comment: If you read the answers you'd see it's the exact same issue because you don't use the exception object. You merely pass the exception message causing you to lose all stack trace info

Comment: LOG.error("Exception", e);

Comment: Is this line have to add in my catch block right?

Comment: Yes, or ideally you pass the entire exception object to your `ServiceException` constructor

Answer (score 1):

The point that Sonar is trying to make is that you ideally print or keep the root cause of your exception, so basically the stack. You keep it by passing the exception object because if you only keep the message you lose all that information. To make sonar happy you either print the stack trace (`log.error(ErrorMessages.EPO_SM_ERR_03, e)`), or re-throw a new exception passing the Throwable object to the constructor.

So the ideal solution would be to use the ServiceException like this;

```java
public class ServiceException extends Exception {
    public ServiceException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

```java
throw new ServiceException(ErrorMessages.EPO_SM_ERR_03, e);
```